# IP address spoofing

Tags: c#, ip-address, spoofing

Is it true that, if I want to make an IP spoofing program, I need only a program that can change my machine IP address?

If true how can I use `System.Net` - `IPAddress` Class to set the ip address?

Comment: If you want to change your IP address, just go change it on the network adapter. For windows: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-your-IP-Address-(Windows)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not true. Changing your machine's IP address is not IP spoofing. IP spoofing is when you create network packets that have a source IP address that does not match the actual IP address of the source machine.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

This could be achieved using RAW sockets or WinPCap using SharpPCap to interop to WinPCap
http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpPcap.aspx

Comment: Also remember, if you spoof your IP address at the packet level you can _send_ information but not _receive_ it

Comment: Good catch. Perhaps Stackoverflow should have an internal glossary on computer science technical terms to help people from other countries to express themselves nicely.

Comment: @Junior Mayhé: Maybe look at http://english.stackexchange.com/. Not technically-oriented, but probably a lot of the same people on it as here.

Answer (score 1):

Your machine IP address is simply the IP address given to your machine to be used internally by devices within your home network. This is how routers, switches and other client devices can deliver and exchange packets.

You cannot spoof your external-facing IP in this manner. Using proxies will make the proxy's IP *appear* to be your external-facing IP.

I do not suggest changing your internal IP unless you know what you are doing and actually have a need for it to be static. For example, I forward ports on my router so I can run services. The router knows to point that traffic directly to my internal IP. Because DHCP can change your IP (due to lease expiration and what not), it's best that I make my internal IP static.

Also, depending on your network configuration, your internal IP has a certain format, like 192.168.1.X.

Comment: Just adding a comment to this, not all IP addresses assigned to a device (such as a computer) are internal.

Comment: Well, yeah. But in the context of what he was talking about (machine ip, etc) it does describe a network device. Sorry if my answer seemed misleading.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't taking into account the context (looking at "your machine").

Answer (score -1):

The best way to http://www.change-ip-proxy.com>change your ip address is through a proxy. In my search for a proxy, I found that having a reliable company behind the proxy is very important. Everything you do is sent through the company’s proxy, so you want to be sure that you can trust them to not read or steal your personal information. Or else there's no point in having a proxy.

Comment: use a proxy is a way to keep your privacy it doesn't your own data security, and I think it should be avoided if he's doing something unauthorized

Comment: Using a proxy is not the same as spoofing an IP address.